What's the fastest way I can open the Google folder in which the spreadsheet is located?
I have opened a Google spreadsheet. What's the fastest way I can open the Google folder in which the spreadsheet is located? Fastest way means with the fewest clicks.

You can open the enclosing folder in two clicks. The top line in the spreadsheet window looks like this:
My spreadsheet ☆ ➲ ☁️
Click the second icon ➲, then click the Open in new tab icon ⇗.


In Sheets select open the Move dialog using either the Move button or the menu File > Move 
Move button
 File > Move
   
In the move file dialog select the open folder icon.   Move Dialog


